# google document ai doesn't parse form

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api-client, cloud-document-ai

I am working with the form parser in google document ai.

when I send the request :

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token) 
-H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" 
-d @request.json https://eu-documentai.googleapis.com/v1beta3/projects/<project id>
/locations/eu/processors/<processor id>:process
```

I obtain a document with no entity
with this structure :

```
{                                                                               
  "document": {                                                                 
    "uri": "",                                                                  
    "mimeType": "application/pdf",                                              
    "text": "Pascal Carrié\nincwo SAS\nx2289475d\nc/ santa isabel, 12, 4D\nN° TVA FR33494952401\n28012 Madrid\n16 rue de La Comète\nIban :\nES76 3023 0047 4866 6328 6612\n75007 Paris\nrib:\nBCOEESMM023\nFRANCE\nFactura nº 2020/02\nFecha\n11/2/20\nConcepto\nPrecio\nCuandidad\nIVA\nImporte\ndéveloppement backend\n4250\n1\n0%\n4,250.00 €\nCondicións de pago : A la recepción de la factura\nBase Imponible\n4,250.00 €\nTotal IVA\n0.00 €\nTOTAL\n4,250.00 €\nForma de pago\nContado\n", 
    "pages": [                                                                  
      {                                                                         
        "pageNumber": 1,                                                        
        "dimension": {                                                          
          "width": 2378,                                                        
          "height": 1681,                                                       
          "unit": "pixels"                                                      
        },                                                                      
        "layout": {                                                             
          "textAnchor": {                                                       
            "textSegments": [                                                   
              {                                                                 
                "endIndex": "431"                                               
              }                                                                 
            ]                                                                   
          },                                                                    
          "boundingPoly": {                                                     
            "vertices": [                                                       
              {},                                                               
              {               ...
```

No analysis at all. What am I doing wrong?

When I upload the same document in the demonstration, it works fine.

I don't think it's base64 related; I have coded my document and obtain a string as describe in the doc

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through the pages->formFields object.
In each object you'll find fieldName and fieldValue, which includes textAnchor->textSegments startIndex and endIndex;
With this information you can substr the "text" property.

Basic sample in php:

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('d:\tmp\response.json'));
$text = utf8_decode($json->text);
foreach($json->pages as $indx => $pag){
    foreach($pag->formFields as $indx2 => $field){
        $from = $field->fieldName->textAnchor->textSegments[0]->startIndex;
        $to = $field->fieldName->textAnchor->textSegments[0]->endIndex - $from-1;
        $name = substr($text, $from, $to);
        
        $from = $field->fieldValue->textAnchor->textSegments[0]->startIndex;
        $to = $field->fieldValue->textAnchor->textSegments[0]->endIndex - $from;
        $value = substr($text, $from, $to);
        $fields[] = [$name => $value];
    }
}
print_r($fields);
```

Comment: thanks, the results I obtains are poors. I made the implementation in ruby. Perhaps my implantation is not good. But anyway I was expecting the entities return from Google (as they claim in the documentation)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated documentation for how to Handle the Processing Response from the [Document AI Form Parser](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/processors-list#processor_form-parser).

- https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/handle-response#forms_and_tables

You can also check out these Codelabs showing how to use the Form Parser in Python and Node.js.

- https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/docai-form-parser-python
- https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/docai-form-parser-node